# jQuery val() giving weird a output

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to get the track list from discogs the output in the console is file but getting a weird output  in the input using `val()`

here is my code

```
$.each(data.tracklist, function(index, TrackName) {
  console.log(TrackName.title); // getting the tacklist 
  $("#album_desc").val(TrackName.title); // getting Hitchhiker 
})
```

this html

`<textarea name="album_desc" id="album_desc" class="bbcode_editor" cols="60" rows="8"></textarea>`

not the tack list as in the console
the api end point `https://api.discogs.com/releases/10927583`

Comment: What do you get in the console, any answer would be based on guessing and prediction without the HTML code relevant and the expected output, please edit your question add a snippet to reproduce the issue you are facing.

Comment: give API call code to help

Comment: It seems you are trying to assign value to input in a loop, you would always get value set last value in the array.

Comment: Do you want to set the value to $ ('# album_desc')?

Comment: yes i want to append the track list to album_desc

Comment: try with ```append()``` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a variable as an array and push all the titles in that array. While adding value to the `textarea`, use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with `\n`

```js
let data = {
  "tracklist": [{
      "duration": "",
      "position": "1",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "Sorry Not Sorry"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "2",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "Tell Me You Love Me"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "3",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "Sexy Dirty Love"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "4",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "You Don't Do It For Me Anymore"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "5",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "Daddy Issues"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "6",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "Ruin The Friendship"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "7",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "Only Forever"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "8",
      "type_": "track",
      "extraartists": [{
        "join": "",
        "name": "Lil Wayne",
        "anv": "",
        "tracks": "",
        "role": "Featuring",
        "resource_url": "https://api.discogs.com/artists/1065010",
        "id": 1065010
      }],
      "title": "Lonely"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "9",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "Cry Baby"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "10",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "Games"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "11",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "Concentrate"
    },
    {
      "duration": "",
      "position": "12",
      "type_": "track",
      "title": "Hitchhiker"
    }
  ]
}
let allTitles = [];
$.each(data.tracklist, function(index, TrackName) {
  allTitles.push(TrackName.title);
});
$("#album_desc").val(allTitles.join('\n'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="album_desc" id="album_desc" class="bbcode_editor" cols="60" rows="8"></textarea>
```